# OpenOffice Headless Mode - Temp Directory?

Tags: headless, files, openoffice

We're running OpenOffice 3.2 in headless mode. It writes all of it's temporary files to /tmp and we're running out of disk space, so I'd like to change the temp directory for it.

Sadly, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this configuration locate in the configurations for all users?

[look at this site](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Handling_the_OpenOffice.org_User_Profile) to see it's location